# Make a call to Convert.ToSingle(string parameter) with Mono.Cecil

Tags: .net, mono.cecil, valueconverter

As title says, I would like to make a call to that method with Mono.Cecil, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**How to inject a method call with `Mono.Cecil`:**

1. Read a target assembly.
2. Find a required point to inject method call. The required point is
   an instruction into a method body with all parameters of injected
   method on stack.
3. Find an injected method.
4. Generate an instruction of call to this method.
5. Insert generated instruction after the required point (from claim
   2).
6. Rewrite the target assembly.

**Code example to inject a Convert.ToSingle(string) call:**

Target method

```cs
namespace YourTargetNamespace
{
    public class YourTargetClass
    {
        public Single YourTargetMethod()
        {
            var str = "1";
            return 0; //Convert.ToSingle(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Injection code and test in a different assembly

```cs
    [Test]
    public void InjectConverToSingleTest()
    {
        InjectConverToSingle();

        var engine = new YourTargetClass();
        Assert.That(engine.YourTargetMethod(), Is.EqualTo(1.0f));
    }

    public void InjectConverToSingle()
    {
        const string assemblyName = "YourTargetAssembly.dll";
        var assemble = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyName);
        var type = assemble.MainModule.GetType("YourTargetNamespace.YourTargetClass");
        var method = type.Methods.First(m => m.Name == "YourTargetMethod");
        var il = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
        var requiredPoint = method.Body.Instructions
            .First(instruction => instruction.OpCode.Code == Code.Ldstr &&
                                  (string)instruction.Operand == "1");

        var convertInstruction = CreateConvertInstruction(assemble.MainModule);
        il.InsertAfter(requiredPoint, convertInstruction);
        il.InsertAfter(convertInstruction, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
        assemble.Write(assemblyName);
    }

    public Instruction CreateConvertInstruction(ModuleDefinition module)
    {
        var typeConvert = module.Import(typeof(Convert));
        var methodToSingle = typeConvert.Resolve()
            .Methods.First(method => method.Name == "ToSingle" &&
                                     method.Parameters.Count == 1 &&
                                     method.Parameters[0].ParameterType.FullName == module.TypeSystem.String.FullName);
        var importedMethodToSingle = module.Import(methodToSingle);

        return Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, importedMethodToSingle);
    }
```