# Injecting a class and wrapping a function around strings

Tags: c#, encryption, mono, mono.cecil

I'm attempting to make an obfuscator and so far it's going well.  Right now I'm trying to encode strings with `base64` and then `rot13` that just to make it an extra bit unreadable and hide my *sooper sekret* strings.

This is what I have for encoding the strings on the obfuscator:

```
ILProcessor processor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
foreach (Instruction instruction in processor.Body.Instructions)
{
    if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldstr)
    {
        instruction.Operand = Enc.to64(Enc.Rot((String)instruction.Operand, 0x0D)); //0x0D = 13
    }
}
```

So now what I need to do is inject my `Enc` class into the root namespace and since the functions are static I'll be able to use them without creating an instance of the class.
Then what I'll need to do is wrap each string in two of the functions in `Enc` to decode the string when the program is actually used, making

```
string lel = "x";
```

into

```
string lel = Enc.from64(Enc.Rot("encoded x", 0x0D));
```

I know how to do neither of these things, so there's where I need your help.

So to recap I need to know how to inject a class (with static functions) into the root namespace and then wrap all strings in the program with two functions from said class so that it's unreadable when reflected but decoded when used.

Comment: Write the code in C#. Then look at the IL. something along the lines of `ld,ld,call,call` instead of `ld`.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Inject a class into user’s assembly.**

If I understand you correctly, you have an `Enc` class in a separate assembly, and you want to create copy of this class in a user’s assembly during the obfuscation. In that case, you could implement creating copy of class using `Mono.Cecil`. You just open two assemblies:

```
var assemble = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(...)
```

find the required class in your assembly:

```
assemble.MainModule.GetType(...)
```

and create a new class with same attributes and members of the user’s assembly:

```
new TypeDefinition(...)
```

There are third-party tools for this task: [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630), [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack), [Mono.Merge](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2006/11/06/an-introduction-to-mono-merge/). You can use one of them or write your own implementation based on them.

**2. Inject a call of method into user’s assembly.**

The `Mono.Cecil` contains everything you need to change an IL code of method body. You will need to parse the existing IL code of methods to find injection points. Parsing algorithm depends on your requirements for transformation code. You can look an example of a method call injection in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957712/1815957).